# drupal 8 contextual filter

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-contextual-filters

I have 2 content types "lab" and "member".  When I display "lab" data, I want to display "member" from this lab.

I defined a contextual filter in a display "entity reference list" of a view, which run in preview.

I defined a reference field in "lab", which "reference method" is the above "entity reference list". But about the views arguments which have to passed to the views?

Regards,
E. Cocquebert

Answer (score 1):

I succedded to have what I wanted.

It was not a "entity reference" display but a "block" display.

"entity reference" is to help to fill the form display

"block" is to display result of the contextual filter when display a specific node (in my case).

Regards,
E. Cocquebert